# How do I grant the privilege to add users to a specific Active Directory group?

Tags: active-directory, permissions, user-permissions, groups

I want give a user privileges to add users to a specific Active Directory group in my domain. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

The user will need rights to modify the `member` attribute on the target group.

[image]